# Javascript map to Associative Array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like so:

```
const content = [
    {
        title: 'Morning run',
        id: 'id1',
        desc: 'Meet at the park',
        date: '2018-01-14T09:00:00.000Z',
        location: 'Central park',
        createdBy: '23432432',
    },
    {
        title: 'Evening run',
        id: 'id2',
        desc: 'Meet by the station',
        date: '2018-01-14T18:00:00.000Z',
        location: 'Central station',
        createdBy: '23432432',
    },
];
```

How can I create an associative array like so?:

```
const output = {'id1' : 'Morning run', 'id2' : 'Evening run'}
```

Can this be done with a map function?

Comment: First a small remark, an associative array doesn't really exist in JavaScript, the `output` notation that you suggest actually is an object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you need just one object in the result, you could use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const content = [{
    title: 'Morning run',
    id: 'id1',
    desc: 'Meet at the park',
    date: '2018-01-14T09:00:00.000Z',
    location: 'Central park',
    createdBy: '23432432',
  },
  {
    title: 'Evening run',
    id: 'id2',
    desc: 'Meet by the station',
    date: '2018-01-14T18:00:00.000Z',
    location: 'Central station',
    createdBy: '23432432',
  },
];

var result = content.reduce(function(accum, currentVal) {
  accum[currentVal.id] = currentVal.title;
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `array#map` with `Object#assign` to create an object with `id` and `title`.

```js
const content = [{ title: 'Morning run', id: 'id1', desc: 'Meet at the park', date: '2018-01-14T09:00:00.000Z', location: 'Central park', createdBy: '23432432', }, { title: 'Evening run', id: 'id2', desc: 'Meet by the station', date: '2018-01-14T18:00:00.000Z',location: 'Central station', createdBy: '23432432', }, ],
      result = Object.assign(...content.map(({id, title}) => ({[id]: title})));

console.log(result);
```

One can also use `Object.fromEntries()` with `array#map` to create the object.

`Object.fromEntries(content.map(({id, title}) => ([id, title])))`

```js
const content = [{ title: 'Morning run', id: 'id1', desc: 'Meet at the park', date: '2018-01-14T09:00:00.000Z', location: 'Central park', createdBy: '23432432', }, { title: 'Evening run', id: 'id2', desc: 'Meet by the station', date: '2018-01-14T18:00:00.000Z',location: 'Central station', createdBy: '23432432', }, ],
      result = Object.fromEntries(content.map(({id, title}) => ([id, title])));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function like this

```
let out = content.reduce(function(a,b){
   a[b.id] = b.title
   return a;
},{})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const map = {};
for(const {id, title} of content)
   map[id] = title;
```

Just iterate over your content and add every entry to the map.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let initVal = {};
    let content = [
    {
        title: 'Morning run',
        id: 'id1',
        desc: 'Meet at the park',
        date: '2018-01-14T09:00:00.000Z',
        location: 'Central park',
        createdBy: '23432432',
    },
    {
        title: 'Evening run',
        id: 'id2',
        desc: 'Meet by the station',
        date: '2018-01-14T18:00:00.000Z',
        location: 'Central station',
        createdBy: '23432432',
    },
];

    content = content.reduce(function(myObj,next) { 
        myObj[next.id] = next.title;
        return myObj; 
     }, initVal );

console.log(content);
```